# How to ignore diacritics with a regex in Android 2.2?

Tags: android, diacritics

I need to use Android 2.2 (API 8) and I have seen that `Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD)` is only available from Android API 9.

What can I add to my regex to ignore accents ?

```
SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

for (String keyword : keywords.keySet()) {

    String caseInsensitiveRegex = "(?i)\\b" + keyword + "\\b";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(caseInsensitiveRegex);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(stringBuilder);

    while (m.find()){

        // Do some stuff

    }

}
```

Thanks per advance for your help ;)

Answer (score -1):

> is only available from Android API 9

Android is open sourced project. There's nothing preventing you from grabbing that part of API 9 and putting directly in your app so you will no longer be API dependent and I at the moment I am not seeing any obstacles for doing this in your case.

Comment: I don't agree with this kind of answer. If it was as simple as you say, everybody were to use API level 1 with code of latest API to be compatible with all android's versions. As I can see on the Google PlayStore, almost all applications are not compatible with API Level 1 ;)
Anyway, if it's simple, in this case, to grab the part of API9 that I want to use, the answer that i was expecting for was this part of API9.

Comment: There's nothing bad in that answer. Many modules can be easily back ported - sure, not all due to missing API but once you got sources of everything you will basically be able to do that (yet, amount of work that you'd need to put it may be sometimes high)